# Visualizing Component Tree in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

In Android View System you can see the UI tree of different elements that make up the view hierachy for example as shown below:

[image]

Apart from Previewing the Composables, I am looking for a way to visualize the Composables in a Component Tree for example given this code:

```
    @Composable
    fun TodoScreen(....) {
    
    Column(){
    LazyColumn{
    
    ...}
    Row{
    
    Button(){....}
    Text(){...}
    
    }
    
    }
}
```

Please let me know if there is a way to display a Component Tree on Android Studio Arctic Fox similar to the above Android View Hierachy Image.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `View -> Tool Windows -> Layout Inspector`

[image]

Comment: It was just there all this time!thanks very much @Gabriele Mariotti. You saved my day as I was working on a huge project and got lost not knowing what is contained where and the fitting in the hierachy.

Comment: @Gabriele Mariotti Nothing shows up in the Component Tree for me.  Are you on the Stable channel for Android Studio?